# Monotone convergence theorem allows the limit to be infinity

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

[Monotone convergence theorem(MCT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem)
 doesn't impose any restriction on the limit.

For example,

if $\{X_n\}$ satisfies $0 \le X_n \nearrow X$ with $EX=\infty$, then I still could use MCT to get conclusion $EX_n \to \infty$.

Can anyone check if it's right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you assume that $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables?

Comment: @saz Yes, I edited. Thanks

Comment: Okay, then you are right.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, saz.